# Curved line: Which dimension?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

A straight line is in $1$ dimension, A square in $2$, but what about a curved line? A straight line looks the same no matter how you look at it but a square doesn't. It looks like a straight line if looked sideways. But a curved line, if looked sideways it looks a shorter straight line. So which dimension does it belong to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A "well-behaved" curve$^\dagger$ such as the ones I think you have in mind, exist in $2$D-space, but the object itself is $1$-dimensional.  There is only $1$ degree of freedom at any point: going forward / backward.  In concrete terms, if $\alpha: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is a parametrization of a line and $\beta$ a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism) from the line to the curve, then the function $\beta(\alpha(t))$ gives the curve with choice of $t$ providing the degree of freedom.

Another example: a hollow sphere of radius $r$ exists in $3$D-space, but the sphere itself is $2$-dimensional.  Specifically, it has parameterization $\alpha(u, v) = \left[ \begin{matrix}
r\cos(v) \cos(u) \\
r\cos(v) \sin(u) \\
r \sin(v)
\end{matrix} \right]$ where, if one is standing at a point, varying the $u$-value provides one degree of freedom and varying the $v$-value the other.  Another way of thinking about this is to note that a neighborhood about a point on a sphere resembles $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the sphere is a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)).   In the plane, any movement in any direction can be decomposed into a horizontal movement and a vertical one: two degrees of freedom / two dimensions.

---

$^\dagger$ The [Hilbert curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) is an example of a curve that is not well-behaved.

Comment: Can you provide a simpler answer? :)

Comment: The words are big but the concept isn't too out there.  One way of thinking about one of the definitions of dimension is as the number of "basis" movements one needs to describe *any* movement at any point on the surface (e.g. horizontal and vertical for the plane, or just horizontal for the real line).  Many "nice" objects like curves, spheres, cylinders and so forth fall into a class of objects called "manifolds".  An $n$-dimensional manifold is one that looks like "n-D" space when you're at a point.

Comment: For instance, the sphere is a manifold because locally it looks like a plane: the Earth's surface looks flat to someone standing in the middle of Kansas.  Likewise, if you have a circle of sufficiently large radius, then walking along it will feel like walking in a straight line (despite very slight curvature).  So if the thing we're looking at "looks like" n-D space at a point, it means that any movement from that point to another close by can be accomplished with $n$ "basis" movements.

Comment: The functions I gave with all the sines and cosines just gives a way of seeing these "basis" movements algebraically.  For the sphere's parametrization $\alpha(u,v)$, let's say we're at the point $p$ given by $u = s$ and $v=t$ for some real numbers $s$ and $t$.  Then to get to a second point $p'$ that is close by, we simply adjust the $u$ and $v$ just a bit; that is to say, if $p = \alpha(s, t)$, then $p' = \alpha(s \! + \! \delta, t \! + \! \varepsilon)$ where $\delta$ and $\varepsilon$ are real numbers small in magnitude.

Comment: So basically, to get from $p$ to $p'$, the two "basis movements" are first adjusting the $s$ so that we go from $\alpha(s, t)$ to $\alpha(s \!+\! \delta, t)$ and then adjust the $t$ so that we go from that point to $p' = \alpha(s \! + \! \delta, t \! + \! \varepsilon)$.  It's similar to how we can get from, say, the origin to the point $(x,y)$ by moving horizontally $x$ units and then vertically $y$ units.  I'm not doing the best job explaining this but perhaps some other denizens of this site can come along and provide a different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

There exist several definitions of dimension, but assuming the curved line is not too wild (for example, is not a fractal line), I don't think there's any that would give anything but $1$.